Laravel Validation - How can I make Rule::in() allow missing/null values?
I use the Laravel validator to dynamically validate a field like so:
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;


                $validator = Validator::make(
                    data: (array)$parent,
                    rules: [
                        'code' => [Rule::in($allowedCodes)],
                    ]
                );

                if ($validator->fails()) { ... }

However, I want to be able to also allow missing/null values.
How can I do this? Adding null in the list of $allowedCodes does not seem to work.
Also, I try to avoid using the string representation of the in rule (that requires concatenating all allowed codes into a string.

Does rules: ['nullable', Rule::in($allowedCodes)] work?

@TimLewis I have tried that, but it didn't work. I guess both rules in the array must be met.

Typically no, since some for rules, it's impossible for all of them to be satisfied... This should work, since  the nullable rule allows the field to be blank (null), and if it isn't null, then it should check against the Rule::in(...) logic. What validation errors do you get when it fails?

@TimLewis Indeed, the reason it appeared not to be working was that I had another bug somewhere.

Oh, yeah, that would do it  All good, glad you got it working, cheers!

To allow for both valid codes and null values in Laravel's Validator, you can modify your rule slightly. Instead of directly adding null to the $allowedCodes array (which doesn't work with Rule::in), you should ensure that null is treated as a valid value by using a conditional rule in your validation.
According to the example in the documentation (https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/validation#rule-in):
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

$validator = Validator::make(
    data: (array)$parent,
    rules: [
        'code' => ['nullable', Rule::in($allowedCodes)],
    ]
);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    // Handle validation failure
}

Alternative (using custom validation):
If for some reason you need a more custom approach (such as adding more complex validation for null), you can use a custom validation rule (example in the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/validation#using-closures ):
$validator = Validator::make(
    data: (array)$parent,
    rules: [
        'code' => [
            'nullable',
            function ($attribute, $value, $fail) use ($allowedCodes) {
                if (!is_null($value) && !in_array($value, $allowedCodes)) {
                    $fail($attribute.' is invalid.');
                }
            },
        ],
    ]
);

